# SWT RowLayout with last element grabbing excess horizontal space?

Tags: java, layout, swt

I have two elements in a horizontal `RowLayout`.
I am able to specify a (minimal) with for the second element (e.g. 200 px). Furthermore...

a) If the total width of the shell is too small, the second element wraps to a new line. That works fine with the `RowLayout`.

b) If the total with is "large", the second (=last) element should **grab the excess horizontal space**.

Is b) possible with the `RowLayout`? Or do I need to use a `GridLayout` and implement the wrapping on my own (e.g. use one or two columns in the grid layout, depending on the size of the elements)?

```
public class RowLayoutDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new RowLayout());

        Text firstElement = new Text(shell, SWT.NONE);
        firstElement.setText("firstElement");

        Text secondElement = new Text(shell, SWT.NONE);
        secondElement.setText("secondElement");
        secondElement.setBackground(new Color(null, 200, 0, 0));

        int minWidth = 200;
        RowData rowData = new RowData();
        rowData.width = minWidth;
        secondElement.setLayoutData(rowData);

        shell.pack();
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RowLayout` does not support what you are looking for. I recommend using a `GridLayout` with a resize listener as you suggested or implement your own layout.

Comment: I still have issues with my custom layout. Maybe you can have a look at my related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45263938/swt-grid-layout-takes-too-much-vertical-space-for-composites-with-custom-layout

Answer (score 0):

I first tried to write a custom layout which turned out to be be hard. The second strategy based on `GridLayout` was easier. Here is a first draft for a custom `Composite` that switches the number of columns of its `GridLayout` to have one or two columns, depending on the size of its children.

(I still have an issues with flickering when resizing my Sections.)

```
package org.treez.core.adaptable.composite;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.ControlAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.ControlEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Layout;

/**
 * A row composite for only two children. If the children are too large for a single line, the second child is wrapped
 * on a second line. The second child always grabs excess horizontal space. This composite automatically sets the
 * LayoutData of its children. Therefore the LayoutData of the children should not be set manually.
 */
public class GrabbingRowComposite extends Composite {

    //#region ATTRIBUTES

    private int widthHintForFirstChild = 80;

    private int minWidthForSecondChild = 200;

    private boolean isSingleLine = true;

    //#end region

    //#region CONSTRUCTORS

    public GrabbingRowComposite(Composite parent) {
        super(parent);
        super.setLayout(createLayout());

        if (parent.getLayout() instanceof GridLayout) {
            GridData gridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.BEGINNING, true, false);
            setLayoutData(gridData);
        }

    }

    //#end region

    //#region METHODS

    private GridLayout createLayout() {

        //create default layout for single line
        GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(2, false);

        //change layout to use several lines if required
        this.addControlListener(new ControlAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void controlResized(ControlEvent e) {
                adaptLayout();
            }
        });

        return gridLayout;
    }

    private void adaptLayout() {

        int totalWidth = this.getBounds().width;

        Control[] children = getChildren();
        if (children.length < 2) {
            return;
        }

        Control firstChild = children[0];
        Control secondChild = children[1];
        int firstChildWidth = children[0].getBounds().width;

        setWidthHintForFirstChild(firstChild);
        setGrapHorizontalSpaceForSecondChild(secondChild);

        boolean isTooSmallForOneLine = totalWidth < firstChildWidth + minWidthForSecondChild;
        if (isTooSmallForOneLine) {
            setTwoLineLayout();
        } else {
            setSingleLineLayout();
        }
    }

    private void setTwoLineLayout() {
        if (isSingleLine) {
            super.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
            updateLayoutOfParentAndGrandParent();
            isSingleLine = false;
        }
    }

    private void setSingleLineLayout() {
        if (!isSingleLine) {
            super.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));
            updateLayoutOfParentAndGrandParent();
            isSingleLine = true;
        }
    }

    private void setWidthHintForFirstChild(Control firstChild) {
        GridData firstGridData = new GridData();
        firstGridData.widthHint = widthHintForFirstChild;
        firstChild.setLayoutData(firstGridData);
    }

    private static void setGrapHorizontalSpaceForSecondChild(Control secondChild) {
        GridData secondGridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false);
        secondChild.setLayoutData(secondGridData);
    }

    private void updateLayoutOfParentAndGrandParent() {
        Composite parent = getParent();
        if (parent != null) {
            parent.layout(true);
            Composite grandParent = parent.getParent();
            if (grandParent != null) {
                grandParent.layout(true);
            }
        }
    }

    //#end region

    //#region ACCESSORS

    @Override
    public void setLayout(Layout layout) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("The layout of this composite must not be changed");
    }

    //#end region

}
```

Example usage

```
package org.treez.core.adaptable.composite;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Color;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.ExpandableComposite;
import org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.Section;

public class GrabbingRowCompositeDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Shell shell = createShell();

        shell.setSize(500, 300);

        Section section = createSection(shell);

        Composite parentComposite = createParentComposite(section);

        createRow(parentComposite, "first");

        createRow(parentComposite, "second");

        createRow(parentComposite, "third");

        section.clientVerticalSpacing = 0;

        showUntilClosed(shell);

    }

    private static Shell createShell() {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);

        GridLayout shellGridLayout = new GridLayout(1, false);
        shell.setLayout(shellGridLayout);
        return shell;
    }

    private static Section createSection(Shell shell) {
        Section section = new Section(
                shell,
                ExpandableComposite.TWISTIE | //
                        ExpandableComposite.EXPANDED | //
                        ExpandableComposite.TITLE_BAR | //
                        ExpandableComposite.CLIENT_INDENT);

        GridData gridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.BEGINNING, true, false);
        section.setLayoutData(gridData);
        return section;
    }

    private static Composite createParentComposite(Section section) {

        Composite parentComposite = new Composite(section, SWT.NONE);
        section.setClient(parentComposite);

        parentComposite.setBackground(new Color(null, 0, 0, 255));

        GridData gridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.BEGINNING, true, false);
        parentComposite.setLayoutData(gridData);

        GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(1, false);
        parentComposite.setLayout(gridLayout);

        return parentComposite;
    }

    private static Composite createRow(Composite parent, String text) {

        GrabbingRowComposite row = new GrabbingRowComposite(parent);
        row.setBackground(new Color(null, 255, 255, 255));

        Label label = new Label(row, SWT.NONE);
        label.setText(text);

        Button checkBox = new Button(row, SWT.CHECK);
        checkBox.setBackground(new Color(null, 255, 0, 0));

        return row;

    }

    private static void showUntilClosed(Shell shell) {

        shell.open();
        Display display = Display.getCurrent();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

}
```